# Why is this mouse event propagating multiple times when the onclick event is functioning properly?

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a custom marker class for a google react app with a google map. I don't understand why the onclick handler here is firing correctly (once per click) but the onMouseEnter handler here fires for every single marker on the google map. How do I achieve the desired behaviour (firing the onMouseOver event only per marker when I mouse over)?

```
import React from 'react';
import './Marker.css';

const Marker = (props) => {
    const { id, name, lat, lng, address, phone, color } = props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className="pin bounce"
          style={{ backgroundColor: color, cursor: 'pointer' }}
          title={name}
          onClick={ () => {
                    console.log("Name: " + name);
                    console.log("Address: " + address);
                    console.log("Phone Number: " + phone);
          }}
          onMouseOver={console.log("mouse over")}
        />
        <div className="pulse" />
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default Marker;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually its pretty clear that you have written onClick with an anonymous function and in onMouseOver you are trying to execute a function. In React you cannot run functions inside an event listner like onClick.
For Example,

```
const handleClick = () =>{
    console.log("clicked")
}
```

To use this function in eventListner onClick you would do (functional component):

```
<div onClick={handleClick}>Button</div>
```

And **NOT** this :

```
<div onClick={handleClick()}>button</button>
```

You are supposed to pass the reference of the function.
So in your case :

```
  <div
        className="pin bounce"
        style={{ backgroundColor: color, cursor: 'pointer' }}
        title={name}
        onClick={ () => {
                  console.log("Name: " + name);
                  console.log("Address: " + address);
                  console.log("Phone Number: " + phone);
        }}
        onMouseOver={()=>console.log("mouse over")}

        <div className="pulse" />
   </div>
```

I hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: i think it does ty very much

Comment: Welcome! Good luck!